# Evaluating the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0+}\left[h(x)\right]^{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0+}\left[h(x)\right]^{g(x)}$$

where $h(x)=\log_{\ |\sin(x)|} x$ , $g(x)=f(x)+|x|$, and

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \leq 0 \\ -x & x >0 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Isn't $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that $\;f(x)=-|x|\;$ and thus $\;g(x)\equiv0\;$ , so 
$$\;h(x)^{g(x)}=h^0=1\;,\;\;\forall\,x\;\;\text{such that}\;\;x\neq0$$

and the limit then equals $\;1\;$ .

Comment: how did you make $g(x)=0$ without knowing the continuity of h(x). i mean how is this possible $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)^{\lim_{x\to o}g(x)}$

Comment: @sharafzaman The fact that $\;g\equiv0\;$ doesn't depend on the continuity of $\;h\;$ or anything else, but only in its definition, which depends only in the definition of $\;f\;$ . Once this is established, observe that $\;h^g=h^0\equiv1\;$ , so the limit is actually a constant function's.

Comment: but how do you know that h(x) is defined or not

Comment: @sharafzaman It is defined whenever $\;\sin x\neq0\iff x\neq k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and since we're interested in $\;x\;$ approaching zero we have no problem, not even with points for which $\;\sin x=1\;$.